# Magento: Setting the default homepage / store when you have multiple stores

Tags: magento

I have a Magento installation with two store versions: Store A and Store B.  When you go to 'mydomain.com' I get this error message:

```
'There was no Home CMS page configured or found.'
```

Until you click on the link for either Store A or Store B -- then it saves the store in a cookie called 'store' and remembers this when you go to 'mydomain.com'.

Is it possible to set 'Store A' as the selected store / homepage by default if no 'store' cookie exists yet?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 30):

In the admin you go to **System -> Configuration -> Web -> Default Pages**

You will have to change to the website / store view that you want to change (the dropdown in the upper left corner). You will probably have to create a new CMS page if you want to have something different from your default home page.

Comment: This is mostly the main issue solution.

Answer (score 5):

go to System -> CMS -> Pages
choose Home Page Cms 
and asign all view states that you want them for this cms
you could do it for another cms too

Comment: your answer is realy good beacuse your answer is realy simple.thanks