# How to set the default store (___store) with Magento, excluding front/home page

Tags: magento

My current Magento website is requesting a store (via lightbox) when the user first arrives on the home page. The user will continue navigating the website and content will appear properly without any issues.

The problem is when they arrive on a sub-page of the website and the store has not been set previously by the user. This also impacts SEO.

Question: How do I set the default store, without affecting the lightbox that is appearing on the home page.

Comment: 1. How many stores do you have? 2. Should the lightbox default to 1 store? or whatever the current store the user is on?

Comment: Currently, there is only 2 stores. I would prefer if the home page keeps the lightbox functionality to select which store the user wants to view, but the sub-pages need to have a default store.

Comment: and how are you changing stores within the lightbox? the `?__store=` querystring?

Comment: Correct (the ?__store query string)

Comment: So basically you want the lightbox to appear even if the user enters through a sub-page?

Comment: Home page to use Lightbox, sub-pages to have a default store if a store isn't already selected.

Comment: I don't understand that part. Don't the sub-pages already have a default store?

Comment: Some sub pages are used in both stores. When you directly navigate to one of the sub pages without going through the home page first, you receive a 404 error. But if you have been to the home page and selected a store, navigating directly to a sub page doesn't cause any errors.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments traded back and forth, it sounds like your default store isn't set properly. If you aren't using any index.php hacks to do with store view setting, you should be able to follow the following steps to resolve this:

[Magento: Setting the default homepage / store when you have multiple stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493271/magento-setting-the-default-homepage-store-when-you-have-multiple-stores)