# There was no Home CMS page configured or found

Tags: magento

I am facing issue after moving files server into local.

I am getting "There was no Home CMS page configured or found."

Also some number appended after the css, javascript and images names like noreload.1506341628.css.

Thanks

Comment: duplicated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493271/magento-setting-the-default-homepage-store-when-you-have-multiple-stores

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?